# WindowsNT.3.5 domain: location of homes

Tags: samba, home-directory

Context: I am working with a Samba PDC (not AD mode) which emulate a MS NT Server 3.5.

My problem is with the following line on `smb.conf`:

```
logon home = \\%L\%U
```

This line makes users mount a `home` share named after their username called with the alphabeth letter specified in the user's LDAP entry:

```
 sambaHomeDrive: Y:
```

My question is: may I change `logon home` to

```
 logon home = \\my_store_server\%U
```

Or I am forced to have homes on PDC?

Comment: What the DNS resolution versus Roaming profile had to do together ?

Comment: From your comment I realize my question was badly written. I changed it in hope to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, %L's value mean the Samba server's NetBIOS name. You can replace that with any server name you want.

Just be aware that the auto creation of home directory can be affected.